# Rails views inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails application with an engine inside it.
Is it possible for the engine to inherit base application view?

I mean, if I have the `#{Rails.root}/app/views` path in the engine's `view_paths`, the views will be searched in:

```
/app/views/my_engine/controller_name/action
```

I need instead to put the views in:

```
/app/views/controller_name/action
```

It is easy to use an application wide layout using the `layout()` method inside the engine, but no luck using base views for each action.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved adding a prefix to the Action View `lookup_context`

```
lookup_context.prefixes << 'controller_name'
```